# jquery - fixed position side menu

Tags: jquery, menu, css-position, fixed

I have a side menu and if the user scrolls past 200px I want it to stay at the top.

This bit is fine, I can detect the scroll and add a class to make it 'fixed'.

The problem is the horzontal position. I have a standard 960 style grid so it need to be responsive.

My #wrapper is 960px, my main col is 640px and this col is 260px.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Comment: show your code ??????

Comment: Use media queries to adjust the main content area and sidebar